# Extranet alert emails have intranet URLs in SP13

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a extranet site that is extended from an intranet site and we have document alert so whenever new document get added it sends out emails it includes the intranet url instead of the extranet url. we would like to change that alert url to extranet.any suggestion?
Thanks
Rav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server name part of URL used in alerts is defined by server name used in the time of alert creation. It means that when you (or your users) use intranet address while defining alert the same intranet address will be used in alert emails. There's no easy (UI) way to change it. You can modify existing alerts by Powershell or in SharePoint database.

Comment: i have followed http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721062.aspx which shows you how to do that with powershell but it didnt work. do you know if i am missing something in there?

Comment: No, article you mention is related to something else. I'm talking about [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc508980(v=office.14).aspx).

Comment: Mazin,Thanks for helping me out on this. i have fixed this issue by changing the Alternate access Mapping and it started working. Thanks again for your help.